# Django CreateView with get_success_url not working for this specific case

Tags: python, django, url, django-views

*I'm using Django 2.1.*
I'm having a problem with a CreateView because I need to redirect to the update url, but that url contains one argument that is created manually after verifying that the form is valid.

This is the view code:

```
class ProjectCreateInvestmentCampaignView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'webplatform/project_edit_investment_campaign.html'
    model = InvestmentCampaign
    form_class = CreateInvestmentCampaignForm
    success_message = 'Investment campaign created!'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('project-update-investment-campaign',
                            args=(self.kwargs['pk'], self.object.campaign.pk, self.object.pk))

    def form_valid(self, form):
        project = Project.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form.instance.investment_type = "A"
        form.instance.contract_type = "CI"
        form.instance.history_change_reason = 'Investment campaign created'
        valid = super(ProjectCreateInvestmentCampaignView, self).form_valid(form)
        if valid:
            campaign = CampaignBase.objects.create(project=project, )
            form.instance.campaign = campaign
            form.instance.campaign.project = project
            form.instance.campaign.creation_date = timezone.now()
            form.save()
        return valid
```

As you can see, on the `form_valid` I validate first the form, and then I create the object campaign and assign all the related data. This is working fine.
The problem came when I changed the `get_success_url` to fit my use case, that is redirecting to the update view.
I debugged and saw that at the moment I create the variable `valid` on the `form_valid`, it checks the success url, and that triggers me the following error:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pk'
Exception Location: /Volumes/Archivos/work/i4b/webplatform/views/investor_campaign_views.py in get_success_url, line 25
```

I asume that the error is because the campaign is not created yet so it's trying to get the `pk` from a non existing object.

The thing is that I cannot create the campaign if the form is not validated, but I need the campaign to make the url working (that url is working as it is on the `UpdateView` that I already have).

Answer (score 0):

It will only invoke `get_success_url` after `form_valid`. So it's up to `form_valid` to create and save the objects needed. If it's valid for them not to be created, you need a different approach. Maybe initialize (say) `self.campaign_pk = 0`, update it if a campaign can be created with the pk of the campaign object, and let the next view sort out what to do when pk==0. Or,

```
...
    args=(self.kwargs['pk'], 
          self.object.campaign.pk if self.object.campaign else 0, 
          self.object.pk))
```

(I don't fully follow your code so I might be barking up the wrong tree here)

It may be that you don't want `CreateView` but `FormView`, which doesn't handle object creation for you, so you may find greater flexibility over how to process a valid form that nevertheless cannot be fully honoured all the time. Or even, just a plain old function-based view, in which you can process two or more forms and be far more able to decide on conditions that constitute non-validity even after all the forms have technically validated.

This is a function-based view structure I have used where I have two forms to process, and a fairly long but boring set of operations to do after BOTH forms validate:

```
def receive_view( request):

    # let's put form instantiation in one place not two, and reverse the usual test. This
    # makes for a much nicer layout with actions not sandwiched by "boilerplate" 
    # note any([ ]) forces invocation of both .is_valid() methods 
    # so errors in second form get shown even in presence of errors in first

    args = [request.POST, ] if request.method == "POST" else []
    batchform = CreateUncWaferBatchForm( *args, layout=CreateUncWaferBatchLayout )
    po_form =  CreateUncWaferPOForm(     *args, layout = CreateUncWaferPOLayout, prefix='po')
    if request.method != "POST" or any(  
        [ not batchform.is_valid(), not po_form.is_valid() ]):

        return render(request, 'wafers/receive_uncoated.html',   # can get this out of the way at the top
            {'batchform': batchform,  
            'po_form': po_form, 
        })

    #it's a POST, everything is valid, do the work
    ...
    return redirect('appname:viewname', ...)
```

Comment: I'm using one single ModelForm with an extra field that then I save it on another model. For this case the field is `end_date` and I save it on the object I'm creating just after knowing the form is valid: `CampaignBase`. Having in mind the  `if` inside the `args`, it will only be used to pass the validation, but then the view itself will get the one with the correct `pk` right? If you think that having the models or any other extra information will help to catch up what I'm trying to explain tell me and I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

For me, `get_success_url` was not invoked as the form was not valid (was `invalid`) and I didn't know. You can override `form_invalid(self, form)` to control the behavior.

Also, consider this block of code to show any errors in your template

```
{% if form.errors %}
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    {% for field, errors in form.errors.items %}
    {% for error in errors %}
    <b>{{ field }}</b>: {{ error }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```